# Macで押したキーを対話式に調べる方法

Tags: macos

Macbookの`かな`と`英数`キーを押した時に送信されるキーコードが何かを調べるために
`xev(1.2.2)`を使ってみたのですが、`control`や`a`,`s`などの記号はキーコードを取得できるのに
肝心の`英数`と`かな`は押しても反応がありませんでした。

以下のページに`英数`が102, `かな`が104と記述されていますが、調べ方そのものが知りたいです。

[Macのキーボード入力、マウスクリックをJavaScriptで (JXA) - Qiita](https://qiita.com/zakuroishikuro/items/afab0e33ad2030ba2f92)

keycodeの確認はどう行うのがよいのでしょうか？

Comment: 2015とか2011なので既に古い知識かもしれませんが、こんな記事が参考になるかも。[How to hook/remap an arbitrary keyboard event on OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30308192/9014308), [OS X: Detect system-wide keyDown events?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4752427/9014308)

Comment: 今手元にMacは無く、かつ随分昔の記憶なのですが、[Karabiner-Elements の EventViewer](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/docs/manual/operation/eventviewer/)でできないでしょうか？